# Conditional Probability and ANOVA or Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, bayesian, anova

There is a pond with fish in it.

1. We know there are certain exact number of fish in the pond.
2. We are fishing with a certain kind of fishing bait. Because we have sophisticated equipment, we know exactly how many fish look at the fishing bait. 3. Some of the fish eat the fishing bait after looking at it.
3. Some of the fish that eat the fishing bait, are hooked and caught.

The questions we need equations for:

1. Based on the exact number of fish in the pond, how many fish need to look at the bait for us to be 95% confident that we have adequately tested the bait’s eye appeal to the fish?
2. Based on the number of fish that look at the bait, how many fish need to eat the bait for us to be 95% confident that we have adequately tested the bait’s taste appeal to the fish?
3. Based on the number of fish that eat the bait, how many fish do we need to hook for us to be 95% confident that we have adequately tested the bait’s catching ability to hook fish?

We need the above equations for different size ponds:

1. A pond with 2,000 fish in it.
2. A pond with 500 fish in it.
3. A pond with 30 fish in it.
4. A pond with 15 fish in it.
5. A pond with 5 fish in it.

Comment: If this is a riddle, this might not be the place to put it.

Comment: Why do you think this is a riddle?

Comment: Take a step back and read it back. You should see it.

Comment: you may hold a preoccupied idea that its a riddle by all means. But this is not. We can see Conditional Probability like if A happens, then the chance of B as well as if both of A and B hold, then what about C. Think in this way. And it demands to find a Mathematical Equation, so we can make Target as a function of Predictors given that the Residuals are Normally Distributed and if the Target and Predictors are Categorical then we can use ANOVA. As this involves Conditional Probability we may use Bayesian. So this question has every basis to be a standard Statistical Problem. It's not riddle.